# create a menu based on the parent of a drupal book

Tags: routes, nodes, navigation

I've been working with the book module bundled with drupal 7 and have a question.
Say i have a book x, and this book contains 4 pages which each have 2 children giving a structure like this:

- Book x

  - Subheading 1

    - Page 1
    - Page 2
  - Subheading 2

    - Page 1
    - Page 2
  - Subheading 3

    - Page 1
    - Page 2
  - Subheading 4

    - Page 1
    - Page 2

What I want to do is create a menu that will sit at the bottom of the page which displays links based on these 4 subheadings, i.e. if you were viewing Subheading 1 the menu would display links to the 2 child pages of the subheading. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my issue, turns out my theme_menu_link function was hiding the book menu block. Once I realised this I placed the block alongside my main menu on the block pages, and used my theme_menu_link to style it.

Comment: By block do you mean the _book navigation_ block provided by the core book module?

Comment: yes, if you set it to only show on book pages it creates the tree of book items; perfect for what I was doing.